# How do I update a Google Sheets Add-On

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have made changes to my (already published) Google Sheets Add-On (in the Script Editor).
I have created a new version and pressed "Publish > Deploy as Add-On" which says

```
You must configure the G Suite Marketplace SDK to publish an add-on.
```

When I click on the link G Suite Marketplace opens (and I see the currently published products catalog entry) but no way of specifying a new version.
.
When I click OK nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire Google Sheets add-on deployment workflow is one hot mess. Do not use `Publish` -> `Deploy as Sheets add-on...` to update an already-deployed AppScript. It does not work.

Instead, first create a version of the script `File` -> `Manage version`. Then go to the `G Suite Marketplace SDK` page in the Google Cloud Platform console (`console.cloud.google.com`). Under the `Configuration` tab, scroll down to find `Editor Add-on extensions` where `Sheets add-on extension` should already be checked (if you followed the publication directions earlier and have already successfully published the add-on).

There you will see a field for the script version number. Increment it to the latest version, and `Save changes`. As far as I can tell this takes effect immediately.

Comment: I’m doing exactly this but the effect is definitely not taking effect immediately...

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Google is currently migrating add-ons from the Chrome Web Store to the G Suite Marketplace, so now need to be published there rather than the legacy marketplace.*

#### Further Information:

In order to publish an Apps Script project as an addon, as specified in your message, the G Suite Marketplace SDK must be configured. You can find an article detailing the migration process [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration).

You will need to enable the G Suite Marketplace SDK in your Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project. You can follow the information on the [Getting Started](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started?ref_topic=6262490&visit_id=637122836455358016-4288036907&rd=1) page for Google Cloud.

#### References:

- [All add-ons now in the G Suite Marketplace](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration)
- [Publish to the G Suite Marketplace](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-gsm)
- [Getting Started with Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started?ref_topic=6262490&visit_id=637122836455358016-4288036907&rd=1)

Comment: I can go to the link see the catalog information (that are already there from the previous version). Click on "save" and get the message that the configuration is now set up correctly. I go than to Publish (in G Suite Market Place). I can click on "Update" and get a message that the update was done. But when I go back in the Script Editor I can still not publish the Add-On (get the same message that I must configure G Suit Marketplace SDK first.) BTW: The Add-On version I get when I open another sheet is still the old one.

Comment: This sounds like a propagation issue which is something you will unfortunately have to wait for. It's been known to take 2-3 days to fully propagate through Google's systems so it might just be this if you're getting a confirmation message saying the update's been done.

Comment: My question is now, what is supposed to happen? Is it enough to update the catalog entry and wait (or do I need to publish on G Suite Marketplace and wait ) or will I have to wait and publish again in the Script Editor after early next week.

Comment: If the G Suite marketplace SDK is enabled and configured, that should be enough. Unfortunately it's difficult to know where the state of your add-on is until enough time has passed to ensure the propagation but after waiting for propagation this will be much clearer.

Comment: My update is still not published (and the message in the Script Editor during Add-On publishing is unchanged). What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

The new GSM publishing flow for Editor Add-ons as described https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/editor-publish-overview is now available.

This means that all updates now needs to be done through GSM. Please make sure to complete all the fields in both the configuration and publish section of the marketplace SDK and click on the 'Publish' button.

Comment: I dd just that (as I did a few days ago). I get a success message, but the Add-On ist still not updated.

Comment: You should wait some days because GSuite Team is very busy during holiday season